# Jetpack URL shortening, fixing after website URL change

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I have a website which uses Jetpacks wp.me shortlinks.
Sadly after the website URL change those are still pointing to the old address.
Is is possible to force regenerate those?

Comment: This site is meant for [WordPress development questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You'd probably be better off asking your question in the [Jetpack plugin support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/jetpack).

Comment: I don't think so. You should set up redirects from your old site to the new one instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just deactivate your Jetpack plugin and again activate JetPack plugin, your issue will be solved. Same issue happened with me and solved with active/deactivate plugin.

Second way inside jetpack setting find shortlink and enable/disable.

Hope this will be help.